# Request data from Programmatically EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm making a class that displays the UI programmatically. I display a lot of EditText and others and i want to request the data of any one to save in the BD. How i can give an id for either one?

Here's the code

```java
            for (int i=0; i<lista.size();i++){
                String dato = lista.get(i).getData_type();
                String title = lista.get(i).getField_label();
                String id = lista.get(i).getField_name();


                if (dato.equals("Text")){
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    Lview.addView(tv);
                    tv.setText("Ingrese "+title);
                    EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                    et.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    Lview.addView(et);
                    et.setHint("Ingrese Datos");
                }
            }

            btnIng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Toast.makeText(plantilla.this, "El elemento es ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i=0; i<lista.size();i++){
            String dato = lista.get(i).getData_type();
            String title = lista.get(i).getField_label();
            String id = lista.get(i).getField_name();


            if (dato.equals("Text")){
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                tv.setId(assignDifferentId)
                Lview.addView(tv);
                tv.setText("Ingrese "+title);
                EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                et.setLayoutParams(lp);
               et.setId(assignDifferentId2)
                et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                Lview.addView(et);
                et.setHint("Ingrese Datos");
            }
        }

        btnIng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(plantilla.this, "El elemento es ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And you can access this by id as following

```
EditText et = Lview.findViewById(yourassignedId)
String text = et.getText().toString()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if i have more that 1 EditText, how i can identify the id of either one? :/